# How to get lambda function name in c++/gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda

How to get lambda function name in c++. In below example it should get "blabla". Other gcc macros don't give a good one.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
auto blabla = []()->void{
    cout << __func__ << endl; // operator()
    cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl; // operator()
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; // main(int, char**)::<lambda()>
};
blabla();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with that name?

Comment: print it out but I'd prefer not to copy-paste them into lambda functions.

Comment: what do you want when you do something like `auto hoo=blabla` ?

Comment: Lambda functions don't have user-readable names.

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible to capture that "blabla" but perhaps not

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if I've ever seen one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda function is an [unnamed function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Also, the `blabla` is a variable which embedded a lambda s.t it has `()` operator to invoke.